# Application freeze on glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl-es, metal

My application freezes on a call to glTexImage2D, this is the stack trace I get from the lldb:

```
  thread #3
    frame #0: 0x00000001bb04d9b4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001bb04dd60 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 76
    frame #2: 0x00000001bdb28dd0 IOKit`io_connect_method + 440
    frame #3: 0x00000001bdb28bec IOKit`IOConnectCallMethod + 236
    frame #4: 0x00000001d5b1b970 IOGPU`IOGPUResourceCreate + 224
    frame #5: 0x00000001d5b159f8 IOGPU`-[IOGPUMetalResource initWithDevice:remoteStorageResource:options:args:argsSize:] + 476
    frame #6: 0x00000001d5b18ab8 IOGPU`-[IOGPUMetalTexture initWithBuffer:descriptor:sysMemOffset:sysMemRowBytes:vidMemSize:vidMemRowBytes:args:argsSize:isStrideTexture:] + 616
    frame #7: 0x00000001d5b1925c IOGPU`-[IOGPUMetalTexture initWithPrimaryBuffer:heapIndex:bufferIndex:bufferOffset:length:descriptor:sysMemRowBytes:vidMemSize:vidMemRowBytes:args:argsSize:] + 96
    frame #8: 0x000000021c45bc10 AGXMetal13_3`___lldb_unnamed_symbol4663$$AGXMetal13_3 + 468
    frame #9: 0x0000000133953aa8 AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer`GLDTextureRec::loadObj() + 3156
    frame #10: 0x000000013398a960 AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer`gldModifyTexSubImage + 160
    frame #11: 0x000000021bd9a7e8 GLEngine`glTexImage2D_Exec + 1944
    frame #12: 0x000000021bd7b8d0 libGL.dylib`glTexImage2D + 80
```

My questions are: how could a call to glTexImage2D freezes and cause the thread stuck forever? Why and how to solve it?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @HamidYusifli I can provide more information. But what else do you interested in beyond what's provided for answering the given questions?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @HamidYusifli Sadly the code is much more complicated and the freeze is not reproducible reliably. This is what I captured. If you are interested in more lldb information, I can provide it. But thanks for your inquiry.

Comment: Yes please. you're welcome.

Comment: @HamidYusifli Sure, can you be more specific about what exactly do you need? As far as I diagnosed that this is the only relevant thread. Thread 3 is blocked on this backtrace, and not proceeding to further execution.